# How does the energy of a supernova compare to that of its parent star?

Tags: energy, stars, supernova, stellar-physics

How can the energy produced in a [supernova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova) be quantified? And, if the energy of the supernova is not equal to the energy of the parent star, how do we account for this difference?

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question in the hope that the edited version will comply with the question guidelines.

Comment: Depends on the type of the supernova. Type Ia are essentially giant nuclear fusion bomb, while core collapse supernova are being driven by gravitational energy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova#Energy_output.

Comment: @CuriousOne Surely the energy ouput could not be greater than the original energy, including the in the form of matter? ($E=m_0c^2$)

Comment: @NoahP: Neither the star nor the supernova can convert all of their mass energy, of course, but hydrogen to helium fusion only converts less than one percent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction), while the gravitational collapse is more than an order of magnitude more efficient (I can't find hard numbers and it's probably not fully understood, yet).

Answer (score 2):

Not at all clear what you mean by "the energy of a star".

A ten solar mass star that explodes as a *core collapse* (type II) supernova releases about $10^{46}$ J, mostly in the form of neutrinos.

By comparison, the total rest mass energy of the star is around $2\times 10^{48}$ J.

Another comparison would be how much energy a star releases during its lifetime. Roughly speaking, the lifetime is 30 million years, the average luminosity around 3000 solar luminosities and the star emits around $10^{45}$J during the majority of its lifetime (about 0.05% of its rest mass).

Clearly then the rest mass energy is not converted into light and photons either before or during the supernova. Where is it? Still in the rest mass energy of the baryons that made up the star, most of which have been scattered into the interstellar medium and the rest locked into a neutron star remnant.

Comment: will the energy released by the sun be greater or less than the energy it will release during it supernova. by how much will any of the situation be greater than the other

Comment: @feminangel errr, the Sun will not end in a supernova.

Comment: wow, i thought all stars go supernova when it is time to die